# Is it possible to load and train a model, if only thing we have is check point files?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

Is it possible to load and train a model from check point files ?
We have information about input and output Tensor shape.

[Check point files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXwGY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use tensorflow-keras following this example.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint

Directly from tensorflow documentation.

## List checkpoints

```
!ls ./tf_ckpts
```

which produces

```
checkpoint           ckpt-8.data-00000-of-00001  ckpt-9.index
ckpt-10.data-00000-of-00001  ckpt-8.index
ckpt-10.index            ckpt-9.data-00000-of-00001
```

## Recover from Checkpoint

> Calling `restore()` on a `tf.train.Checkpoint` object queues the requested restorations, restoring variable values as soon as there's a matching path from the `Checkpoint` object. For example we can load just the bias from the model we defined above by reconstructing one path to it through the network and the layer.

```
to_restore = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5])) # variables from your model. 
print(to_restore.numpy())  # All zeros
fake_layer = tf.train.Checkpoint(bias=to_restore)
fake_net = tf.train.Checkpoint(l1=fake_layer)
new_root = tf.train.Checkpoint(net=fake_net) 
status = new_root.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./tf_ckpts/')) 
print(to_restore.numpy())  # We get the restored value now
```

To double check that it was restored you can type:

```
status.assert_existing_objects_matched()
```

and get the following output.

```
<tensorflow.python.training.tracking.util.CheckpointLoadStatus at 0x7f1d796da278>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if the checkpoint contains **parameters** of the model (parameters as W and b in W*x +b). I think you have that, in case of **transfer learning**, you can use this based on your files.

```
# Loads the weights
model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
```

You should know the architecture of the model and create the model before using this. In some models, there is a specific way to load checkpoint.

Also, check this out: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Comment: I don'y know the architecture of the model. All I have is checkpoint files and input and output tensor shapes.
So, how can I create a model before loading it?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without architecture.